# Undefined index: client_id" on line 1001

Tags: php, laravel

any help you offer on this will be useful. Am working on my school project and this error code keeps popping up on the application "Undefined index: client_id" on line 1001"

Here is the code

```html
public function onNewclientaddress(){
    $addShipmentForm  = Settings::get('addShipmentForm',true);
    $data = post();

      = \Spot\Shipment\Models\Address::where('user_id', $data['client_id'])->update(['default' => 0]);

    if ( $addShipmentForm == "add_form_normal"){
        $subitem = new \Spot\Shipment\Models\Address;
        $subitem->name              = htmlspecialchars($data['street_addr']);
        $subitem->user_id           = htmlspecialchars($data['client_id']);
        $subitem->street            = htmlspecialchars($data['street_addr']);
        $subitem->city              = htmlspecialchars($data['city_id']);
        $subitem->zipcode           = htmlspecialchars($data['postal_code']);
        $subitem->country            = htmlspecialchars($data['country_id']);
        $subitem->default           = 1;
        $subitem->created_at        = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $subitem->updated_at        = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $subitem->save();
    }
    else{
```

line 1001 is the first line of code in the post. please pardon my English

Comment: this simpy means that there is no `client_id` in your data. What happens if you `dd($data)` ?

Comment: (FYI, the code you have _currently_ shown will never show that error, it won’t get that far - because it contains a parse error.)

Answer (score -1):

This error indicates that `$data['client_id']` is not being set. You will need to ensure that whatever form is providing this data, is passing `client_id` correctly.

You can see what is currently in `$data` with a line like:

```
die(var_dump($data));
```

This will output the data on the page.

Ensure your `client_id` field in your form has a `name` attribute:

```
name="client_id"
```

Comment: in Laravel you can simply use `dd()` instead of  `die(var_dump())`

Comment: Absolutely right. My main job only uses some components of Laravel and I always forget about `dd()`! Good shout!